# AWS instance private IP changing after stop/restart (did not happen before)

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Yes, I read an article by Eric Hammond [here](http://alestic.com/2011/09/ec2-reboot-stop-start) where he mentions that the private IP would also change when restarting. A few months ago, when I first got an AWS cluster up for hadoop, I used the internal IP to configure /etc/hosts and the internal IP wouldn't change (even when the instance is stopped, i can see the internal IP).

To replicate this cluster as part of our corporate account, I created a few AMIs and used those to launch the instances. Now, the IPs are changing each time the machine is restarted.

On checking the machines that did *not* have the IP change, there doesn't seem to be anything special about them. They are the same simple EBS backed instances with volumes. Hmm, so what's the difference between them?

Comment: Is your new EC2 instance inside a VPC?

Comment: No, my new instance is just part of our corporate account but no VPC stuff happening.

Comment: Instances inside VPC will retain their private IP addresses when stopped and restarted. But instances outside VPC (ie. EC2-Classic) will change their private IP address when stopped and restarted.

Comment: Yeah I see that the corporate account instances have no VPC associated with them while the ones I created have some VPC associated (although I didn't create it! a default one?) If it's default one, why did it not take effect when I got it in another account?

Comment: Got it, it must be because before 2013 August, they did not have default VPC. hmm, damn :( this means a lengthy migration process to move to a VPC?

Comment: I have created an answer based on my comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether your EC2 instance is inside a VPC or not.

Instances inside VPC will retain their private IP addresses when stopped and restarted. But instances outside VPC (ie. EC2-Classic) will change their private IP address when stopped and restarted.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to move an EC2 instance from EC2-Classic to EC2-VPC. However, in many cases, you can create an AMI image of the instance and launch a new instance from the AMI inside the VPC.